# How to use iOS VisionKit when browsing a document from local library?

Tags: ios, swift, visionkit

Using `VisionKit`, we can let user scan a document using camera like this:

```
let documentCameraViewController = VNDocumentCameraViewController()
documentCameraViewController.delegate = self
present(documentCameraViewController, animated: true)
```

But what should we do if the user browse a document from the `iOS` device locally without involving camera? **Any chance we can still use visionkit to autocorrect on the paper orientation or edges?**

Answer (score 1):

u can use `UIImagePickerController` to browse images locally.

Instead of `VisionKit`, you can use `Vision` to autocorrect on the paper orientation or edges

- Prepare an Input Image for Vision
- Create Vision Requests
- Interpret Detection Results

> apple's [sample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_objects_in_still_images)

Comment: Sounds like still a lot of work to do to autocorrect the distortion of the paper etc.